# How to create a data structure in a Python class

Tags: python, class

```python
class CD(object):
        def __init__(self,id,name,singer):
                self._id = id
                self.n = name
                self.s = singer

        def get_info(self):
                info = 'self._id'+':'+ ' self.n' +' self.s'
                return info

class collection(object):
        def __init__(self):
                cdfile = read('CDs.txt','r')
```

I have a file 'CDs.txt' which has a list of tuples look like this:

```
[
("Shape of you", "Ed Sheeran"),
("Shape of you", "Ed Sheeran"),
("I don't wanna live forever", "Zayn/Taylor Swift"),
("Fake Love", "Drake"),
("Starboy", "The Weeknd"),

......
]
```

Now in my collection class, I want to create a CD object for each tuple in my list and save them in a data structure. I want each tuple to have a unique id number, it doesn't matter they are the same, they need to have different id....can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple loop with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for this.

```
# I don't know what you mean by 'file has list of tuples',
# so I assume you loaded it somehow
tuples = [("Shape of you", "Ed Sheeran"), ("Shape of you", "Ed Sheeran"),
          ("I don't wanna live forever", "Zayn/Taylor Swift"),
          ("Fake Love", "Drake"), ("Starboy", "The Weeknd")]

cds = []
for i, (title, author) in enumerate(tuples):
    cds.append(CD(i, title, author))
```

Now you have all CDs in a nice, clean list

If your file is just the list in form `[('title', 'author')]`, then you can load it simply by evaluating its contents:

```
tuples = eval(open('CDs.txt').read())
```

Comment: do you mean cds.append(CD(i ,title ,author)) ?

Comment: It gives me a UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4903: ordinal not in range(128) What does this mean?

Comment: @joe Maybe try `open('CDs.txt', encoding='utf-8')` instead?